# BSOD after replacing video card

Tags: windows, drivers, bsod, graphics-card

I recently replaced a ATI 6870 with a GTX 670 and am no longer able to access windows from my primary hard drive.

As Windows begins to load there is a blue screen which is rapidly gone and the computer restarts.

I was able to use a new hard drive and install Windows and the computer works fine which suggests there is no hardware problem. I installed the old hard drive and can access the files but cant boot from it.

Is this likely a video card driver problem? is there anyway I can change the drivers without booting from it? any ideas on any other possible problems that could be solved?

Comment: 1) What OS are you using? 2) Will it start in safe mode?

Comment: "Is this likely a video card driver problem? is there anyway I can change the drivers without booting from it?" The answer to both these questions is **Yes**

Answer (score 0):

Press F8 rapidly before starting windows screen appear.

Choose Safe Mode with networking.

Download new driver of your GPU. And install it. Reboot your PC

Comment: And uninstall the old drivers.